# Tune SQL Server Express using Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, tuning

I have a SQL Server 2005 database... a copy of it is running in development on a full version of SQL server. Another copy is running in SQL Server 2005 Express on a web server.

I've used SQL Profiler and saved a Tuning trace log from activity on the SQL Express copy of the database.

I want to use the saved trace log in the Database Engine Tuning Advisor...

If I try when connecting the Advisor to the Express database, I am told that Express is not supported.

If I try when connecting the Advisor to the SQL Server database, I get empty results.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to tune an identical database on the local development server using trace data collected from a remote production server (Express).

But you cannot use trace tables stored in the remote server to do this.
According to [Considerations for Using Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187835(v=SQL.105).aspx), "Database Engine Tuning Advisor cannot tune a workload in a trace table that resides on a remote server"

But I guess you are using trace files, so this should not be an issue.

If you don't get any recommendations, you should first check the list on the previously mentioned [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187835(v=SQL.105).aspx):

> Database Engine Tuning Advisor might
>   not make recommendations under the
>   following circumstances:
>
> The table being tuned contains less
>   than 10 data pages.
>
> The recommended indexes would not
>   offer enough improvement in query
>   performance over the current physical
>   database design.
>
> The user who runs Database Engine
>   Tuning Advisor is not a member of the
>   db_owner database role or the sysadmin
>   fixed server role. The queries in the
>   workload are analyzed in the security
>   context of the user who runs the
>   Database Engine Tuning Advisor. The
>   user must be a member of the db_owner
>   database role.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a copy of the database from the Express instance restored to the full instance.  The advisor looks at the schema to make it's tuning advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is trace the DB to a table  and then point tuning advisor at the data in the table that contains the trace results.  That way I dont think you need to move any databases around.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that I could edit the trace file in SQL Profiler and remove any columns that specify the login or database name.  After that, the Tuning Advisor worked.